# Subview keeps moving when I push and pop navigation controller

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, subview, tabbar

[image before pushing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SiSC.png)

This is what it's supposed to look like originally. The slider's added as a subview of the main view from Xib file on viewWillLoad, and I don't add it again if the subview exists on viewDidLoad. When I push, I call hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on the other view controller.

This is what I happens when I pop back:

[image after popping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qKTw.png)

I have no idea why the subview does that.

Comment: Please describe in detail what is your problem.If you able to attach a screen sort then please attach what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have set for bottom slider in `viewDidLoad` is the first time setting when view comes appear on screen. After that you have hide slider on push action, and goes to second view….right?
But when you come back to your view with pop, then how view can identify that it have show or hide that slider…? So, when you come back-I mean pop that time `viewWillAppear` is called. Put you code there…

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // whatever you want to do, this is just for suggestion
    if (bottomSlider.hidden == TRUE) {
        bottomSlider.hidden = FALSE;
    }
    else {
        bottomSlider.hidden = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never hide my slider when I pop, and I just check if the slider is a descendant of the superview on viewDidLoad to add it to the view. It still moves, and only doesn't move when I don't hide the tabbar